# Oracle SQL : Intersect tuple literals

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a function or operator or otherwise simple(r) construct to obtain the intersection of two tuple literals in oracle sql?

Taking into consideration the following example:

**Having the following table**

```
------------------------------
TABLE sometable
------------------------------
id | telephone | mobile | fax
------------------------------
 1 | 123       | 456    | 789
```

Given a list of n numbers { n1, n2, n3, ... , n }
find id, such that:

```
   telephone = n1 or mobile = n1 or fax = n1
or telephone = n2 or mobile = n2 or fax = n2
or telephone = n3 or mobile = n3 or fax = n3
....
or telephone = n  or mobile = n  or fax = n
```

Two plausible solutions are:

**1. Solution 1**

```
SELECT id FROM sometable
WHERE
   n1 IN (telephone, mobile, fax)
OR n2 IN (telephone, mobile, fax)
OR n3 IN (telephone, mobile, fax)
....
OR n  IN (telephone, mobile, fax)
;
```

**2. Solution 2**

```
SELECT id FROM sometable
WHERE
   telephone IN (n1, n2, n3, ..., n)
OR mobile    IN (n1, n2, n3, ..., n)
OR fax       IN (n1, n2, n3, ..., n)
;
```

**However is there a function / operator to do the following?**

```
SELECT id
FROM sometable
WHERE
 intersect_function
 (
    (telephone, mobile, fax),
    (n1, n2, n3, ..., n)
 )
 = TRUE
;
```

An alternative, simpler construct would be welcomed, taking into consideration that this condition is part of a longer query with more numerous and possibly more complex conditions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My idea is to convert your search numbers into a table via the `with` clause:

Then with a little regexp trick you can create, from a single row, one row per value, and match them against your table thanks to `in` clause:

```
create TABLE sometable
(
  id number, 
  telephone number, 
  mobile number, 
  fax number
);

insert into sometable values(1, 123, 456, 789);
insert into sometable values(2, 0, 0, 123);
insert into sometable values(3, 456, 0, 0);

with w(n) as
(
  select regexp_substr('123, 456', '\d+', 1, level) n
  from dual
  connect by regexp_instr('123, 456', '\d+', 1, level) != 0
)
select *
from sometable s, w
where w.n in (s.telephone, s.mobile, s.fax)
;
```

This gives as expected:

```
ID  TELEPHONE  MOBILE   FAX  N
1   123        456      789  123
2   0          0        123  123
1   123        456      789  456
3   456        0        0    456
```

Comment: `select regexp_substr('123, 456', '\d+', 1, level) n
  from dual
  connect by regexp_instr('123, 456', '\d+', 1, level) != 0`

is very helpful. once you break it into a table the possibilities are numerous.

one interesting thing i have noticed is the cost of the query seems fixed whereas the solutions 1 and 2 the costs are the same and tend to vary.

Answer (score 1):

By creating your own type and function you can achieve something very similar to your desired SQL:

```
SELECT id
FROM sometable
WHERE
 intersect_function
 (
    num_tab(telephone, mobile, fax),
    num_tab(123, 456)
 ) > 0;
```

First you need to declare this type:

```
SQL> create type num_tab is table of number;
  2  /

Type created.
```

... and this function:

```
create or replace function intersect_function
  ( p_tab1 num_tab
  , p_tab2 num_tab
  ) return number
is
  l_intersect num_tab;
begin
  l_intersect := p_tab1 multiset intersect p_tab2;
  return l_intersect.count;
end;
```

However, be aware that by calling a function for each row of data and without being able to make use of indexes this may not be the most performant solution!

Comment: this is also a great way to break the data into tables. my preference however goes to the technique suggested by @Emmanuel because it avoids the need to create a custom type and performs better.

Comment: Yes, that's two good reasons to go with @Emmanuel's solution.